# Webview Android Application

Tags: web, webview

I have a Android app with Web View.

my website 100% responsive and show correct in safari and chrome,
but i have problem show in android default browser and webview apps.

app link
http://go.dadebaran.ir/index.php?url=http://dl.dadebaran.ir/appsource/Web2App-v2.0.rar

Answer (score 0):

Android WebViews do not support the full extent of common desktop or even mobile browser capabilities. A good way to make sure that the problem you are seeing is related to the WebView limitations is try to open your URL on the Chrome Android app.